# xtk volume.image property

Tags: xtk

I am returning to using the xtk library after a short break and I am having issues using the  volume.image getter method [documented here](http://api.goxtk.com/volume.html#image_get). Is this method still supported or was it dropped in moving from version 8 to version 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the code and tried it out - it still works for me!

It should return an empty array if the volume was not loaded and the image data once the volume was loaded.

Comment: Sorry must be a problem with my setup somewhere, thanks for checking